# Nginx fall-through urls with caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have Rails app that has routes matching static files that are generated on first access.

Everything works fine if I have this block commented out in my site.conf:

```
 location ^~ /uploads/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

Is there a way to have best of both worlds and have `location` block to be only activated if the actual file exists and fall-through if it isn't? Maybe add `try` inside?

Comment: You could use `try_files` for that

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes thanks! Added another try_files inside the location block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of best practices  to serve response based on logic "local disk static file vs. dynamic response with backend" is try_files:

```
location ^~ /uploads/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  try_files $uri @backend;
}

location @backend {
  proxy_pass ...
}
```

See official docs [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).